# YII Select2 Dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a code where I want to display the countries data along with the country code. The dropdown must contain both the name and the code. I want that whenever a user selects a country the select bar must display only the code, not the name. for example if a user is from Canada the select bar should display +1. I am using select2 widget in yii2 for dropdown; Here is my code:

```
$countriesIsdData = ArrayHelper::map($countries_isd_codes, 'countries_isd_code','countries_name');
echo $form->field($model,'country_code')->widget(Select2::classname(),  
        [
            'data' => $countriesIsdData,
            'value'=>$count,
            'options' => [
                'id'=>'country_cod', 
                'placeholder'=>'Select Country Code', 
                'prompt' => 'Select Country Code','value'=>$count
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true,
                'dropdownCssClass'=>'bigdrop',
                'value'=>$count
            ]
        ])->label('Country Code');
```

Comment: If you want to display code instead of country_name then need to change:
$countriesIsdData = ArrayHelper::map($countries_isd_codes, 'countries_isd_code','countries_isd_code');

Comment: But it removes the name from the dropdown. I don't want to remove the name from the dropdown. I just don't want the name when a specific country is selected.